# Firebase - filtering on a list

Tags: android, firebase, filtering, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an android app and I need to store some data about users, like their firebase cloud messaging token. My data can be something like this where the id of a user is his phone number :

```
{
    "users" : {

        "+34.....56" : {
            "fcm_token" : "...",
            ...
        },

        "+34.....45" : {
            "fcm_token" : "...",
            ...
        },

        ...
    }
}
```

The thing is that I want every user to see which of his contacts are using the app. So I have a list of phone numbers (contacts of the user), and I want to filter the users of my database with this list. I know that `equalTo()` method can only filter on a single value.

How can I do ? If I make a request with `equalTo()` for each phone number, it will be very painful and costly. And if I make a request to get all of the users of the database and then filter on the client side, it will be very costly as well.

Filter on a list of phone numbers is a very important thing on my app. Is firebase adapted to this, or should I use other database ?

Comment: If you store the users by their phone number, you won't need `equalTo()`. Aside from that, the operation is a lot faster than you seem to expect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen : but how can I do without using `equalTo()` ? I need to compare each phone number of my list with the phone numbers on the firebase db. I didn't know about send multiple requests at the same time

Comment: There is no way to send multiple such requests at one time, nor is it needed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: How can you do that exactly? You just fire off multiple requests in the same time and wait for each of them to return the requested content?